# Hole punching a VPN kill-switch

Tags: shell-script, firewall, vpn, firewalld

I use `firewalld`'s direct rules to block all incoming and outgoing connections except for on a `tun` interface, making a kill switch for my VPN connections (similar to [here](https://airvpn.org/forums/topic/15061-firewalld-killswitch/)).

I have since whitelisted specific VPN servers, and can connect to them directly.

Now I want to automate this process, and in doing so have to fetch statistical load data from my VPN provider's website.

I was thinking of calling something like

```bsh
stats=$(curl provider.com/server/stats | *sed and grep extraction*)
```

but this requires DNS resolution, which is blocked at the moment. Is there a simple way, in shell scripting, to punch a hole in the firewall to temporarily only allow **this one request**?

I don't want to completely disable the firewall temporarily, possibly causing leakage.

### Edit

Creating a proxy network or proxy machine feels like overkill.
Is this truly such a complicated problem?
I am seeking a solution simple in execution.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to set a local proxy and open the way out for it in the firewall. By default you wouldn't use it, but just keep it for special occasions.

Comment: Do you mean another machine on my network acting as proxy?

Comment: @palmtree Either another machine on the network or a localhost proxy.

Comment: Hmmm... That would work. Though, then there would be an "uncontrolled" egress.

Comment: @palmtree This could be controlled by a simple script (start up the proxy & open the firewall for it). But I can't think of a simple way to set up such a localhost proxy now... (I'd have to think.)

Comment: Okay. Please let me know.

Comment: @palmtree Take a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux This seems complex to set up, but then you'd get simplicity in use. The process gets its own interface and it's easy to control in the firewall.

Comment: How about pairing the proxy idea above with port forwarding and single packet authentication: So normally the traffic would not be passed on. Only after succesful SPA (separate machine acting as proxy, which could be a VM) the connection would be fowarded transparently (prevents uncontrolled egress)